# Preserving generics when wrapping functions

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define a function that can wrap an arbitrary function while preserving parameter types and the return type. I have it working when the function doesn't have generics, but am struggling to get it working with generics. Here's a simplified example:

```
function wrap<F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(test: F) {
  return (...args: Parameters<typeof test>): ReturnType<typeof test> => {
    return test(...args);
  };
}
```

```
function simpleTest(a: number): number {
  return a;
}

// works
// type: (a: number) => number
const wrappedSimpleTest = wrap(simpleTest);
```

```
function genericTest<T>(a: T): T {
  return a;
}

// doesn't work
// type: (a: unknown) => unknown
// desired type: <T>(a: T) => T
const wrappedGenericTest = wrap(genericTest);
```

```
function genericTest2<T, U>(a: T, b: U): T|U {
  return Math.random() < 0.5 ? a : b;
}

// doesn't work
// type: (a: unknown, b: unknown) => unknown
// desired type: <T, U>(a: T, b: U) => T|U
const wrappedGenericTest2 = wrap(genericTest2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific behavior you're looking for here can be achieved by using TypeScript's [support for higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions), implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30215](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215).  Generally speaking the language is not able to abstract over generics this way in the type system; that would require *higher kinded types* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), and TypeScript doesn't have that.  Instead, it uses some heuristics with some specific limitations and requirements to try to infer generic function types this way.

Here's one way to get it working:

```
function wrap<A extends any[], R>(test: (...args: A) => R) {
  return (...args: A): R => {
    return test(...args);
  };
}
    
const wrappedGenericTest = wrap(genericTest);
// const wrappedGenericTest: <T>(a: T) => T 

const wrappedGenericTest2 = wrap(genericTest2);
// const wrappedGenericTest2: <T, U>(a: T, b: U) => T | U
```

I replaced your `F` type parameter with a pair of type parameters `A` and `R` corresponding to the arguments and return types.  The problem with using `F` here is that [the `Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [the `ReturnType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) are [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and the compiler loses track of the generics.

By using `A` and `R` directly, the compiler can keep track of the higher order type operation and you get the generic function type you desire.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOAeAgogUwA8oCwATAZ0XTAE8BtAXQBpEAlAPgApTKoAXIm4A6MelQBzSkNwBKRAF5OHBQG8AUIkSoCUEKiSjxUmYnlD2SlZu3bd+w4j5RjIidLkBuLYgC+Pn4aGqCQsAiIlDAAtpgANgQAKgT83OhCYCDRAEYEqHIZWbmoiLY6egZI6IHBGhAI-CgYmJgE5ADKMfFJKVBKTVjcUbEJyfzewaHQ8EiSZHkwEGNQ2Ik86YiJBZulvg6VNDV1DX1oWK3kAOLzqIvL-WeY3HNgC0u9EwD0n4j1YI2PC7XV63d78ISrdZCLbWTaTcDTCIvN7LABMqzYAFUoZs2NkhJjtolEAAfRCY3b2CpOACy6CgAAsRBgKHBotwFNhEAAGEQAVkQAH4aIghNkjn8Ac0gTc7r1UQ9ms9ZWCoKivj9JadpW1gSj5RDElicUbEPjyQplDsyZigA)